# What linq provider to sqlite on mono platform?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, sqlite, mono

I want to use sqlite database in my asp.net project. I prefer linq, but I don't know which linq provider is compatible with mono platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC [dblinq](http://code2code.net/DB_Linq/) does why you need, and I *believe* it is now included in mono by default.

Comment: Yes, I heard about it, but I'm seeking still some other methods. Otherwise I try to use dblinq :)